# Angular insert subtemplate into main template based on some id

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a sub-template that generates a table with some entries. This table is specific for each day, that means, it has some kind of "day" identifier:

```
@Input() day:number;
```

now I want to insert that template in my main template, which is a tabbed Pane panel that has 7 tabs for each day. I want to insert the corresponding data table with my data for each day, into the corresponding day tabs. Based on the day id or some other day identifier... how can I best do this?

This is my tabs template:

```
<mat-tab label = "Monday">
<app-sub-template-per-day></app-sub-template-per-day>
.....

  <mat-tab label = "Tuesday">
  <app-sub-template-per-day></app-sub-template-per-day>
.....
```

my sub-template table is:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    ......
```

so my question is, how can I create a specific sub-template table in the .ts file that can be identified by its day? And how do I bring this template in into my tab Panel template correctly identified by the day?

I am using angular material for those components

Answer (score 0):

Your table wrapper component ("sub-template" as you call it) needs to take care of providing the correct data to the table through its own data input. Since the table itself doesn't care what data it has (`<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">`) you need to control that through your `<app-sub-template-per-day>` component. For example:

App:

```
<mat-tab label = "Monday">
<app-sub-template-per-day [myDataSource]="getDataSource('Monday')"></app-sub-template-per-day>
...

<mat-tab label = "Tuesday">
<app-sub-template-per-day [myDataSource]="getDataSource('Tuesday')"></app-sub-template-per-day>
...

getDataSource(day: string) {
    // return the data for the matching day
}
```

Component:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="myDataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    ...
</mat-table>

@Input() myDataSource: any;
```

You don't have to use a `getDataSource()` function - you can just point to an actual data object. For example `<app-sub-template-per-day [myDataSource]="myData.monday">`.